# Pentaho Data-Integration

Tags: pentaho

Configurei o PDI para acessar um servidor FTP e baixar um arquivo em csv, até aí está tudo bem, o problema é que dentro da pasta no servidor FTP haverá sempre mais de arquivo, exemplo:

> ```
> REC_PEND_FECH_COM20180219130059.csv
> REC_PEND_FECH_COM20180219132200.csv
> REC_PEND_FECH_COM20180219134000.csv
> .
> .
> .
> ```

Ou seja preciso copiar sempre o arquivo mais atual, como fazer isso?
Aqui usei o shell script no pentaho para fazer o FTP e copiar os arquivos (Mget na pasta), mas não sei como especificar para capturar sempre o arquivo mais recente dentro do diretório, o nome do arquivo é dinâmico `(REC_PEND_FECH_COMaaaammddhhmmss.csv)`

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um tópico que me ajudou a resolver o problema: 
[Link](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/78054-Getting-One-file-with-date-on-the-FTP/)

Comment: Olá, Edvaldo! Por favor, forneça a solução na sua resposta, pois este link que citou pode ficar indisponível algum dia e, assim, poderemos ficar sem a resposta.

Comment: use uma etapa Select values ​​para converter os metadados da data no formato de string que você precisa usando o padrão "aaaaMMdd". 
Então você pode usar essa variável em sua etapa Obter um arquivo com FTP como um caractere curinga $ {YOUR_DATE}

Comment: você pode editar sua resposta e adicionar estas informações nela.

Answer (score 0):

Através do STEP de JOB não há muitos filtros a serem utilizados, porém é possível efetuar uma listagem dos arquivos de um FTP utilizando o step Get File Names em conjunto com [VFS (Virtual File Systems)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html), desta maneira você podera efetuar filtros e ordenações de modificação de data, ou até extrair o timestamp do nome do arquivo para efetuar o filtro.

EDIT:
Um exemplo de utilização seria:
ftp://master:1234@ftp.meuftp.com.br/local/
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vale notar também que alguns FTP utilizam a configuração de modo Passivo, para estes FTPs será necessário adicionar o Parametro:

vfs.ftp.PassiveMode = true

No ktr onde será utilizado o VFS.

Comment: Como que será feita a ligação do GET File Names com o VFS ? É possivel usar o FileZilla ?

Comment: Utilizar o FileZilla através do PDI não sei como seria feito, atualizei a resposta com um exemplo de VFS no Get File Names

Comment: Era para abrir um exemplo, listando arquivos ? estão dando erro.

Comment: Qual foi o comando que você utilizou no step Get File Names para acessar o FTP ?

Comment: Não cheguei a utilizar o Get File Names, pois não sei como implementa-ló.